# присваивание строки элементу массива в си

Tags: c, строки

Можно ли присвоить элементу массива строку определенной длины? К примеру есть массив char STR[4]; и строки char OBJ[31];

Считываем строки из файла:

```
fscanf(obj, "%s\n", &OBJ); //считываем строки 10 раз
```

Затем делаем цикл от 1 до 10(столько строк в файле):

```
for(a=;a<=10;a++)
            {
                STR[a] = OBJ1;
            }
```

Какой код должен быть в теле цикла, чтобы присваивание происходило успешно?

Comment: А что такое STRANA ? в вопросе сказано только про STR и он сам обычная строка из 4х байт. А так вам нужен массив указателей на строки (`char *STR[10]`) и внутри цикла использовать например функцию `strdup()` для выделения памяти под строку и копированию строки в эту память. P.S. не забывайте освобождать память выделяемую `strdup()` после использования, она от `malloc()` отличается только копированием

Answer (score 1):

В языке Си строк нет. Если вам нужно прочитать что-то, что состоит из последовательности символов (например строки из файла), то для таких целей используется понятие `NULL-terminated string` ([wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0)) - это указатель `char*` на область памяти неопределенного размера, который должен заканчиваться `'\0'` - нулем, проще говоря

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

Нет, присваивать строки нельзя. Это будет присвоение указателей без дублирования самой строки. Чтобы скопировать строку правильно, с копированием всех ее символов и корректной работой с памятью, используется функция [strdup](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strdup) - тут по ссылке есть пример, который детально разбирает ваш случай

Обратите внимание:

> Чтобы освободить место, используемое созданной копией, необходимо
>   вызвать free

Answer (score 0):

Для начала: если у вас 10 строк, то почему в STR - 4 элемента?
Что касается вопроса: конкретно так сделать нельзя, так как одному элементу char можно присвоить только 1 байт (1 символ). Для того, чтобы сделать то что вы хотите нужен массив строк (указателей). Вам нужно объявить *STR [10] - тогда у вас будет массив указателей, которые будут указывать на ваши строки. Каждому STR [a] нужно будет присвоить указатель на нужную вам строку. Но не делайте это через массив - я так понял он перезаписывается, так что если будете присваивать указатель на массив - у вас все будет указывать на одну строку, которая введена последней. В общем вам нужна ф-ция malloc и strcat (последняя, если решите записывать строку в массив, а уже потом в массив указателей).